# Работа с телеграм ботом

Tags: telegram-bot

Может ли бот отправлять сообщения с сервера определённому пользователю по номеру телефона или логина?

Answer (score -1):

Вроде бы я нашёл ответ на собственный вопрос. Да, можно отправлять на конкретный номер сообщения, но если у вас есть чем поделится, буду рад почитать ваши ответы

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).